# How to find a function that gives me the indexes of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

Let a square matrix M with size *m*, and let *i* and *j*, given $0 \leq i = j < m$, so that $a_{ij}$ is a value of the matrix located in the row *i* and column *j* (assuming that we start counting with 0 like most programming languages do). I want to find a function $f(i,j)$ that maps the indexes of the matrix in a arbitrary order so that $M_{f(i,j)}=a_{ij}$.

For example the function $f(i,j)$ that maps columns first then rows would be the function $f(i,j) = mi + j$. So the matrix with *m = 3* where $M_{f(i,j)} = f(i,j)$ would be this:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2\\
3 & 4 & 5\\
6 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

But let's say I want a different way to map the matrix, let's take for example that I want to map it diagonally so the matrix where $M_{f(i,j)}=f(i,j)$ would be this:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 6\\
5 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there any known method that I can apply to find the $f(i,j)$ that maps the matrix in this case (or in any other arbitrary way that I come up with)? Or must I know beforehand all the $f(i,j)$ that maps the matrix in useful ways (for example knowing that $f(i,j) = mi + j$ maps it with columns first than rows)?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646117/how-to-find-a-function-mapping-matrix-indices

Comment: @Haus Partially. I stumbled on this question while searching for an answer, but the response to this question only answers how to find a function for the specific case mentioned in the original question, which is find the upper triangle. It did help me get some progress on my problem, which is finding the function that maps the matrix diagonally inverted (almost the one that I mentioned in my question, but subtracting the resulting *f* from $m^2$). What I want to know if there is a method or algorithm to get to these kind of functions instead of trying to crack the desired function everytime